# Boost::log::string_literal construction issue

Tags: boost, boost-log, boost-logging

I'm trying unsuccessfully to use the macro `BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE` with no hard-coding (e.g no `BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE("bla")`, but `BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE(some_variable)`; this macro uses inside a `boost::log::string_literal` that have no C'tor for `std::string` or `char*`. The only thing it accepts is `const char[]` (NOT `const char*`) - which doesn't help me at all because I can't hard-code it - this value must be retrieved from a function.

So, I need to find a way to construct `boost::log::string_literal` with `std::string` or `char*`, or somehow to edit `const char[]`... (I tried also to create a `char[]` and cast it to `const char[]`, but failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erm. "String literal" says it all. It will only work with literals, and those *are* by definition (in the standard, that is) `char const[]`.

This design decision (to make names known and fixed at compiletime) can have several reasons. Conceptually, it will make logging "predictable" (if scope names vary, how are you going to interpret logs?), and might have to do with performance (it could even be used to statically disable some logging based on the scope name, but other things like output formatting could see improved performance depending on the compiler).

So, you can wish to not hardcode things, but you cannot wish to use the macros which require a string literal while doing so.

Now, you *can* use `extern` variables of the appropriate type (`extern char const some_scope_name[]`) which would at least give you the opportunity to define the value in another translation unit, I suppose.

Comment: Tnx.
The reason I need this is to gain logging with filename only (and not full path, as the scope attribute gives).
I guess I'll do this with special formatter-function (using boost::bind to attach it to the sink), or I'll use a macro of the filename for each file in the project (I'll write it manually or via script) and use BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE

Comment: In case it helps anyone, such formatter already exists (these days), using %F instead of %f to drop the full path: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.formatters.named_scope